# let bindings and constructors in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I am defining a stopwatch in F#:

```
open System.Diagnostics

let UptimeStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
```

and I am printing every 3 seconds with

```
printfn "%A" UptimeStopwatch.Elapsed
```

and every time i'm getting "00:00:00.0003195" or something similarly small.  Is F# calling the constructor every time I reference UptimeStopwatch?  If so, how do I get around this ad achieve the desired result?  This is a confusing intermingling of functional and imperative programming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

F# seems to interpret statements like

```
let MyFunction = DoSomething()
```

and

```
let MyFunction() = DoSomething()
```

differently.  The first binds the return value of `DoSomething()` to the variable `MyFunction`, and the second binds the action `DoSomething()` to the function `MyFunction()`.

My usage of `UptimeStopwatch` was correct, and the error was elsewhere in my implementation.

Answer (score 2):

I see you already found a problem elsewhere in your code, but the two lines in your question still take some time to run and, interestingly, you can make the overhead smaller.

When I run the two lines in your sample, it prints a value around 0.0002142. You can make that smaller by storing the elapsed time using `let`, because there is some overhead associated with constructing a representation of the `printf` format string (the first argument):

```
let UptimeStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
let elapsed = UptimeStopwatch.Elapsed
printfn "%A" elapsed
```

This prints on average a number around 0.0000878 (two times smaller). If you use `Console`, the result is similar (because the `Elapsed` property is obtained before `Console` is called and nothing else needs to be done in the meantime):

```
let UptimeStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
System.Console.WriteLine(UptimeStopwatch.Elapsed)
```